# Python Cpp API And Immutable Strings

Tags: python, c++, cpython

I'm currently working on a project using [this open source library (nanobind)](https://nanobind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exchanging.html#mutable-reference-issue)
and am trying to understand how python enforces immutability. Lets say I have some memory allocation in C with the following:

```
std::string& func(){
  auto ptr = malloc(10);
  auto str = new (ptr) string("abcdefghij", 10);
  return *str;
}
```

using nanobind, the above returns a python string by reference to the allocation. Now lets say that I have a way to get access to ptr (the address of the str returned to python) in another function and do something like

```
memcpy(ptr, "bbb", 3);
```

If I'm updating the memory address where the python string is stored, why doesn't the string itself change in python? I know it's immutable, but not sure how that's really enforced here if I'm not copying/returning by reference.

Here is some detail on nanobind's return by reference policy:

*"Create a thin Python object wrapper around the returned C++ instance without making a copy, but do not transfer ownership to Python. nanobind will never call the C++ delete operator, even when the wrapper expires. The C++ side is responsible for destructing the C++ instance."*

Comment: `std::string` it's not a Python string. You got a memory leak in `func()`. You can't do `memcpy(ptr, "bbb", 3);`, `std::string` is not an array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Doing placement new of a standard string is also likely wrong - it's very unlikely that a `std::string` will be 10 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is linked in the documentation you showed:

> The reason is that type casters **convert function arguments and return values once**, but further changes will not automatically propagate to across the language barrier because the representations are not intrinsically linked to each other.

You can read the (very simple) [conversion code for `std::string`](https://github.com/wjakob/nanobind/blob/master/include/nanobind/stl/string.h#L32-L35) and see for yourself:

```
    static handle from_cpp(const std::string &value, rv_policy,
                           cleanup_list *) noexcept {
        return PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(value.c_str(), value.size());
    }
```

where `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html) as:

> The buffer is copied into the new object.

So any changes you make to the source string are not visible in python because python has its own private copy.